# Behaviour of clear function on dart List

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
int a=4;
  var b=a;
  var c=[1,2,3];
  var d=c;
  b.truncate();
  d.clear();
  print("$a,$b,$c,$d");
}
```

**Output**
`4,4,[],[]`

Anyone please explain it.
Why it is clearing `c` also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything you can place in a variable is an object, and every object is an instance of a class. Even numbers, functions, and null are objects. All objects inherit from the Object class.

When you assign an object to another, dart makes a copy by reference, unlike for basic types (int, bool etc.) where it only copies the current value.

When you use `var d=c` d will point (refer) to whatever value stored at the memory address of list c. Any change in either c or d will impact both of them.

If you want to work with a deep copy (meaning that d takes values from c and then exists on its own) you will have to use `...` : `var d = [...c];`

If you are interested about these behaviors I would suggest that you read more about "by reference or by value" and about pointers in C language.

Comment: Dart does not have basic types as such. All values are objects and are "copied by reference". It's just that for immutable values like integers and booleans, it's very hard to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple `d` and `c` have same `List` Object. So if you do anything on `d` or `c`, it will affect the same `List` Object.

```
void main() {
    int a=4;
      var b=a;
      var c=[1,2,3];
      var d=c;
      b.truncate();
      d.clear(); // because d and c have same list object
      d.add(8); //even if you add anything it will go to the same object
      print("$a,$b,$c,$d");
    }
```

This will be the output if you add a item to `List` `d`.

**OUTPUT:**

```
4,4,[8],[8]
```

If you want two List Object then use this :

```
  var c = [1, 2, 3];
  var d = List.from(c);
```

Now if you clear List `d` :

```
d.clear();
```

Only `List` `d` will get cleared as `List` `c` have another `List` `Object`

**OUTPUT :**

```
4,4,[1, 2, 3],[]
```

Answer (score 0):

On equating the 2 lists ,changes in one list will be reflectd in the other too. If you want the same values in d also then rather then equating them you can do:-
**d.addAll(c);**

Answer (score 0):

Dart variables do not hold objects, they hold *references to objects*.

In object oriented programming, objects have *identity*. An object can be distinguished from a different object which otherwise has the same state (using the `identical` function, which checks whether two object references reference the same object). Having identity is why you can change an object's state - the object will maintain that change over time because the object exists over time. Objects exist independently of whether there are variables referencing them.

Two different variables can hold references to the same object.
That's what's happening here. The `c` and `d` variables reference the same single list object, and the `clear` method on lists change the state of the existing object, it doesn't create a new object.

Consider this:

```dart
void main() {
  num a = 4.4; // Bind `a` to (a reference to) the double `4.4`
  num b = a;   // Bind `b` to the same (reference) value as `a`.
  var c = [1,2,3]; // Bind `c` to (a reference to) a new list (call it List#1).
  var d = c;       // Bind `d` to the same (reference) value as `c` (List#1).

  print(identical(a, b)); // "true". It's the same (reference) value.
  b.truncate();
  print(b); // "4.4", `truncate` doesn't change the object, it returns a new one.
  b = b.truncate(); // Changes the (reference) value bound to `b`
  print(identical(a, b)); // "false"
  print(b); // "4"
  print(a); // "4.4" - didn't change the (reference) value bound to `a`
  
  print(identical(c, d)); // "true". It's the same object (reference).
  d.clear();
  print(identical(c, d)); // "true". It's still the same object (reference).
  print(d); // "[]" - clear *changed* the (referenced) object's state.
  print(c); // "[]" - and that *object* is now an empty list.
  d = []; // Create (a reference to) a new empty list and bind `d` to it.
  print("$c - $d"); // "[] - []". Now (references to) different empty lists
  c.add(1);
  print("$c - $d"); // "[1] - []". Now (references to) different lists
}
```

Technically: Objects exist and have identity independently of everything else. Objects are not *values* in the language in the sense that expressions evaluate to values and variables store values (they're neither expressible, denotable, nor storable). Instead *references* to objects are values that expressions evaluate to and which can be stored in variables. When you create a new object using `new Foo()`, the object starts existing, and the expression evaluates to a reference to the new object.

In most cases, this distinction between objects and references isn't important enough for people to say "reference to object" all the time, so most of the time the "reference to" is implicit when we talk about "objects". It's still necessary to understand the underlying distinction because it explains what happens when two variables contain references to the same object (aka. "aliasing"), and that an object referenced by a variable can change state even when accessed through a different variable.